# Jhipster Liquibase Modified Entity via Entity Manager but DB not modified

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, jhipster

So, I modified an entity using the entity manager of JHipster, But it resulted in Liquibase's CheckSum validation errors.

Then I tried the

```
./mvnw liquibase:clearChecksums
```

But it didn't have any effect. So, I manually placed null at the MD5SUM column for those particular entities in the DATABASECHANGELOG entity.

Now, Liquibase recomputed the checksums on its on in the next build. So, NO validation errors occurred and built smoothly, but when i checked my H2 db hadn't been updated, it was the same old database. Although, all Java domain files and liquibase entity xmls have the modifications I made.

Comment: See https://jhipster.github.io/development/#using-a-database

Comment: @AntonNovopashin
Hi, I had read that, and IDK it seems like a bug or something, Im using JHipster 4.0.0. 
According to the docs the DB should reflect new changes made with the entity sub-manager upon restart, but it doesn't.